# How to know if connection has been made

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I am trying to access and insert data with c# using ado.net. I have the sql server installed in my computer and hence I feel the machine name will be the server name. Following are the steps I am using to connect to the database.

```
private void dbButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         connectionString = "Server = ITSL-SALT-33; Database = sampleADO; User Id = sa; Password = abcd;";
         try
         {
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
             conn.Open();
             MessageBox.Show("Successfully connected to the database.");
             insertButton.Enabled = true;
             loadButton.Enabled = true;

         }


         catch (Exception exc)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
             MessageBox.Show("Connection attempt failed");
         }
    }
```

Below is the code for insert Button:

```
private void insButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       cmdString="INSERT INTO books (name,author,price) VALUES (@val1, @va2, @val3)";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.CommandText= cmdString;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", txtBook.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", txtAuthor.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", txtPrice.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", txtComments.Text);
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(conn.DataSource);
        Console.WriteLine(comm.ExecuteNonQuery());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("In Insert catch");

    }
}
```

When I am trying to insert data, it is always showing in the messagebox that "in insert catch". I cannot understand where is the fault or if there is any step I am missing. I am new in using database or sql stuffs, just trying to learn how to interact with a database in .net. Please guide.

Comment: Well, what's the messsage in the Exception that you're catching? Don't just output "In Insert catch", that's useless. Output `exc.Message` as well.

Comment: You are catching a general exception, `Exception`. You may catch specifig SqlException and look at the error number, or for your current Exception you may look at the exception details, it could be something other than the connection

Comment: See whats in your exc variable.

Comment: As I can see, you're trying to establish connection and hold it 'forever'. It's not a good approach, you should try to connect, do your thing and close it. Something like _using (connection) {do-my-thing}_

Comment: paste your exc.ToString() output here.

Comment: Don't you think that dbButton_Click should be invoked before insButton_Click?

Comment: @bhusanFirake : yes, as you can see in the code that I am enabling the insert button within the dbButton_Click method if a successful connection is made. Anyways, the problem is solved now, the way Sidhart Penta mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a just a small mistake just change you `@va2` in your `INSERT` query to `@val2` and it should work now..

`cmdString="INSERT INTO books (name,author,price) VALUES (@val1,` **@va2**, `@val3)";`